# Quarkus UnsatisfiedResolution Exception for ConfigProperties as Object

Tags: java, quarkus

I'd like to inject my quarkus configuraition as an object as described here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings

But somehow Quarkus CDI does not find my configuration bean. I get the error message:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.liquido.util.LiquidoConfig and qualifiers [@Default]
```

`LiquidoConfig.java`

```
@StaticInitSafe     // <=== adding this also didn't help
@ConfigProperties(prefix = "liquido")
public interface LiquidoConfig {
    public String frontendUrl();
    public int loginLinkExpirationHours();

    public Jwt jwt();
    public interface Jwt {
        public String secret();
        public Long expirationSecs();
    }

}
```

And in my Service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public void SomeService {
    @Inject
    LiquidoConfig config;   // <=== this fails???
}
```

I also tried to add @ApplicationScope to LiquidoConfig, although i wouldn't think this is necessary. But also doesn't help.

I can inject my configuration properties individually as:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "liquido.jwt.expirationSecs")
Long expirationSecs;
```

This works. But not as one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.@ConfigProperties` should be replaced by `io.smallrye.config.@ConfigMapping` (as per documentation)

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. This solves my problem. Didn't see that I seem to have been using a deprecated property:  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/22101